# SWT Text field: make text focused at the end of the line

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface

I have an Java SWT Text which I set a long text to. When the shell opens, I want the text to be focused at the end so the user can se the ending of the text.

This is what I got:

```
    Text text = new Text(new Group(parent, SWT.NONE), SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    text.setText(someLongText);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
```

I tried with SWT.RIGHT but it didnt help.

To illustrate what I mean, I used the save functionality in MS Paint. The first picture is what I want to achieve. The second is what I get.

[Desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSnpb.png)

[Current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo78T.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the selection to the end of the text:

```
text.setSelection(text.getText().length());
```

Testing on macOS this only works if the `Text` has the `SWT.MULTI` style rather than `SWT.SINGLE` but on other platforms it might work with `SWT.SINGLE`.